# Multiple target build with jenkins ios

Tags: ios, jenkins, continuous-integration, xcodebuild

I am using jenkins for making auto build (.ipa). Right now I am getting success with single target. But my project has two target "target1" & "target2".

I am trying too many solution from but not getting any success.

So, anyone please help me configure my project to generate .ipa for multiple targets in one project.

Thank you in advance...!!

Comment: Try using `-alltargets` in jenkins `xcodebuild` command

Comment: not working. Right now i am using Xcode Schema File name for creating an .ipa...

Comment: Can you add the script how you're creating the build?

Comment: I am not using script. I am just add Xcode Build option